# Can't shrinkwrap a plane around

Tags: mesh, modifiers, shrinkwrap

I have been learning Blender, I have a complete human model but I want to wrap a small plane around the bottom left leg, like a strap/belt.

Before I did the shrinkwrap operation, my model looks like this. A plane with no modifiers and a duplicated part of leg mesh where I want to wrap. (Human model from MakeHuman)
[image]

After I apply the skinwrap modifier it looks like this. Though I increase the length of the plane, it never makes a complete circle around the leg. I have tried will all options but failed. Is there some way to accomplish this ?

[image]
[!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZsCS8.png)[image]

I want to wrap my plane around the leg mesh. Can someone help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: a different approach would be to use that slice of leg as your starting point for the belt/strap. Select everything, extrude it out with E then S to scale it out (constrain the z axis with shift+Z) and it fits perfectly around the leg :)

Answer (score 2):

It won't work this way, you first need to make it rotate around the cylinder, for example with a *Simple Deform* in *Bend* mode:

[image]

Then shrinkwrap.